# How to change margin of transparent background of dialog window in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, margin, transparent

In android I want to change margin of transparent background of dialog popup window in adapter.My code is as follow

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600,600);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.horo_popup_window);

    TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text1.setText("THIS WEEK'S TAURUS HOROSCOPE");

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText("Step out of your usual role, Taurus. Doing this every now and then can add knowledge and expand your life. The day's planetary aspects favor such growth. Your willingness to walk a different path can give you far more than you imagine. Try something you've never considered before. Go to a new place. Change your desk around. See what you can discover about yourself and the world.");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.taurus1);

    ImageButton dialogButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    dialog.show();
```

`
I want something like as shown in this picture

[image: Dialog Picture]

Comment: use dialogfragment for that

Comment: Can you please explain with any example?